# comparing 'ZoneInfo*' in LogCat

Tags: android, logcat

I get a lot of messages in my LogCat (thousands) that appear as Error messages and all start with `comparing 'ZoneInfo*'`. My App does not crash and have no problems, but what do these messages mean and why am I getting them?

These are the ones I get:

```
09-03 01:03:56.535: E/jdwp(294): >>> comparing 'ZoneInfo*' to 's/Message'
09-03 01:03:56.535: E/jdwp(294): >>> comparing 'ZoneInfo*' to 'os/Looper'
09-03 01:03:57.055: E/jdwp(294): >>> comparing 'ZoneInfo*' to 's/Handler'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Who prints it

It's printed by the Dalvik Java Debug Wire Protocol implementation, i.e. the code that allows you to debug your app, setting breakpoints and inspecting variables etc. Considering the [comment](https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/blob/6bcf5d200bc9d1be6c3d766005c19694a325da61/vm/jdwp/JdwpEvent.cpp#L425) just above the print:

```
    // TODO: remove printf when we find a test case to verify this
    LOGE(">>> comparing '%s' to '%s'",
        pattern+1, target + (targetLen-patLen));
```

I'd say you can safely ignore them, since they apparently are temporary.

### Possible cause in your case

One way to create these prints is to add a Step Filter in Eclipse:

*Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Step Filtering*

If you add and activate a `*ZoneInfo*` filter, you'll get this output when you step into some class. Note that the logcat print strips the first '*'. If you don't have a Step Filter like this, you probably have some other Debug filter somewhere in Eclipse that includes a `*ZoneInfo*` string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have *ZoneInfo* and other Step filters, why do I get *ZoneInfo* only? Also, why is it considered an error (LogE) and not an info?

Comment: The code path with the log print is only hit for step filters that begin with '\*', so I guess ZoneInfo is your only step filter that begins with '\*'. I don't know why it is logged as an error, because it clearly is not an error, but I would guess they log it as an error to always get a log output, even when the log level is high and info log prints are suppressed.